# $f(x)$ vs $f(\{x\})$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

**Example**: $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$. What is $f^{-1}(\frac{1}{3})$? What is $f^{-1}(\{\frac{1}{3}\})$?

My guess is that: either $f^{-1}(\frac{1}{3})$ is undefined as it has two target values and $f^{-1}(\{\frac{1}{3}\})=\{-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}\}$; or both are undefined.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by $f^{-1}$ and how you are defining $f$ because $f$ is invertible over $[0,\infty)$ for example

Comment: @PeterForeman The domain of $f^{-1}$ is intentionally unrestricted; that's part of the reason I'd like clarification.

Comment: Look at these 3 pages for answers to this question: (1) page 4 on http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~genovese/class/iprob-S06/readings/apF.pdf; (2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Examples; (3) https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-f-x-and-f-x-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, strictly speaking, $f^{-1}(a)$ is undefined if $f$ has no inverse, it is usual to use the expression $f^{-1}(a)$ as meaning the same thing as $f^{-1}\bigl(\{a\}\bigr)$.

Comment: And is my interpretation $f^{-1}(\{a\})=\{-\sqrt{a-1}, \sqrt{a-1}\}$ in the OP correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.